# Adobe Air iOS app and Facebook Review

Tags: xcode, facebook, air, adobe, review

our app was rejected by Facebook. They need a simulator binary package of our iOS app.

How to deal this with an Adobe Air iOS app ? Since we dont compile with xCode.

link provided : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/creating-ios-simulator-build-for-review

Answer (score 0):

Answer from a Developer Operations, at Facebook :

If you're unable to create a simulator build you should provide the Review team with as much information as possible. This should include:

- an explanation for why you can't submit a simulator build.
- screenshots that show your Apps use of Facebook login.
- screenshots that show content shared back to Facebook (if you're requesting publish_actions)
- a screencast (video) of your app being used for Facebook login and showing how each permission you request is used to enhance peoples experience.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you need to do is:

1) build a .ipa to run in iOS simulator: 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ios-simulator.html

2) change the extension of .ipa for .zip and uncompress.

3) inside of this folder you will found a .app that you should compress to .zip and send it to Facebook.